# Expand Pandas Series Of Dicts Into Columns (With Missing Values)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas series where *most* elements are dictionaries. I want to expand the dictionaries so they become columns. When there are no missing values, this is easy:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.Series([{'Class': 'A'}, 
                   {'Class': 'B'}])

data.apply(pd.Series)
```

Output:

```
Class
0   A
1   B
```

However, in my case there are missing values. When I try the `.apply(pd.Series)` method when missing values are present, I get an error:

> RuntimeWarning: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and
>   'str', sort order is undefined for incomparable objects   union =
>   _union_indexes(indexes)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data_with_missing = pd.Series([{'Class': 'A'}, 
                                np.nan,
                                {'Class': 'B'}])

data_with_missing.apply(pd.Series)
```

Output:

```
Class   0
0   A   NaN
1   NaN NaN
2   B   NaN
```

What I want is an output like this:

```
    Class
0   A
1   NaN
2   B
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data_with_missing.apply(lambda x: np.nan if pd.isnull(x) else list(x.values())[0])
```

Use a lambda function to check the case that the value is null. in that case return np.nan, else extract the value from the dictionary

```
# ouputs

0      A
1    NaN
2      B
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

using `dropna` with `thresh`

```
data_with_missing.apply(pd.Series).dropna(thresh=1,axis=1)

  Class
0     A
1   NaN
2     B
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to define a custom function to define how you want to treat different types:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

s = pd.Series([{'Class': 'A'}, 
               np.nan,
               {'Class': 'B'}])

def formatter(x):
    return x['Class'] if isinstance(x, dict) else x

s.apply(formatter)

# 0      A
# 1    NaN
# 2      B
# dtype: object
```